# Determine consecutive days within a given window

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #t1 (ID varchar(1), SpecDate date)
CREATE TABLE #t2 (ID varchar(1), Alert varchar(1), AlertDate date)

INSERT INTO #t1 (ID, SpecDate) VALUES ('A', '2021-05-10')
INSERT INTO #t1 (ID, SpecDate) VALUES ('B', '2021-05-10')
INSERT INTO #t1 (ID, SpecDate) VALUES ('B', '2021-05-12')

INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('A', 'N', '2021-05-06')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('A', 'Y', '2021-05-06')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('A', 'Y', '2021-05-07')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('A', 'Y', '2021-05-08')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('A', 'N', '2021-05-09')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('A', 'N', '2021-05-10')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('A', 'Y', '2021-05-11')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('B', 'N', '2021-05-07')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('B', 'Y', '2021-05-08')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('B', 'N', '2021-05-09')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('B', 'N', '2021-05-10')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('B', 'N', '2021-05-11')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('B', 'N', '2021-05-12')
INSERT INTO #t2 (ID, Alert, AlertDate) VALUES ('B', 'N', '2021-05-13')
```

#t1:

| ID | SpecDate |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2021-05-10 |
| B | 2021-05-10 |
| B | 2021-05-12 |

#t2:

| ID | Alert | AlertDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | N | 2021-05-06 |
| A | Y | 2021-05-06 |
| A | Y | 2021-05-07 |
| A | Y | 2021-05-08 |
| A | N | 2021-05-09 |
| A | N | 2021-05-10 |
| A | Y | 2021-05-11 |
| B | N | 2021-05-07 |
| B | Y | 2021-05-08 |
| B | N | 2021-05-09 |
| B | N | 2021-05-10 |
| B | N | 2021-05-11 |
| B | N | 2021-05-12 |
| B | N | 2021-05-13 |

I need to find the count of consecutive 'Y' Alerts from #t2 where at least 1 of the 'Y' is within 2 days prior through equal to SpecDate of #t1, ignoring anything after SpecDate and grouped by ID. There can be multiple values of Alert for each ID and AlertDate (if sensor is moved).
The final output I am looking for is:

| ID | SpecDate | ConsecutiveAlertDays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-05-10 | 3 |
| B | 2021-05-10 | 1 |

I have gotten to finding the 'Y' within the specified window, but can't figure out how to count consecutive, especially when the count leaves the window:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
    , t1.SpecDate
    , t2.Alert
FROM #t1 AS t1
INNER JOIN #t2 AS t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.Alert = 'Y' AND
    t2.AlertDate BETWEEN  DATEADD(DAY, -2, t1.SpecDate) AND t1.SpecDate
```

**Edit** I was trying to keep the problem as simple and generic as possible, but I think some context might help.  I'm working with healthcare data and, for a given day (#t1), I need to know if a patient has had a urinary catheter within the last two days.  If yes, then I need to know how long they have had it.  #t2 has a daily flag 'Y'/'N' indicating if they had one.  There is always at least one daily record, but there can be multiple entries if the patient transfers or has a catheter status changes.

Comment: How do you get "2021-05-10" when those dates are "N"?

Comment: The date in the final output is t1.SpecDate.  I don't need t2.AlertDate in the output, just need it for use in the 2 day window and then counting consecutive days.  The code snippet I have so far only returns a distinct 'Y' that there was an alert in the window (another field that I ultimately need).

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood your question.  I still have a count even though the Alert value is 'N' on '2021-05-10' because both 'A' and 'B'  had an alert on '2021-05-08', within the 2 day window of '2021-05-10'

Comment: I hope you triple check the answers you get given... I'd hate to hear a patient got the wrong treatment because of an incorrect query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after - thank you for the table structure and sample data, but I suspect you'll have other edge cases you didn't include:

```
;WITH src AS -- group in case more than one 'Y' on a day
(
  SELECT ID, AlertDate
    FROM #t2 
    WHERE Alert = 'Y'
    GROUP BY ID, AlertDate
),
groups AS -- make some islands of consecutive days
(
  SELECT ID, AlertDate, day_group = DATEADD(DAY, 
    1-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AlertDate), AlertDate)
  FROM src
),
agg AS -- get the count and last day in each island
(
  SELECT ID, AlertDate, 
    c = COUNT(*)       OVER (PARTITION BY ID, day_group),
    m = MAX(AlertDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, day_group) 
  FROM groups
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.SpecDate, ConsecutiveAlertDays = agg.c
  FROM agg
  INNER JOIN #t1 AS t1
    ON agg.m >= DATEADD(DAY, -2, t1.SpecDate)
   AND agg.m <= t1.SpecDate
   AND t1.ID = agg.ID
   AND agg.m = agg.AlertDate
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.SpecDate;
```

Results:

| ID | SpecDate | ConsecutiveAlertDays |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-05-10 | 3 |
| B | 2021-05-10 | 1 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8db7aa72712439b532aa9a52ae2faca)

Answer (score 0):

Gaps and islands problem. Sounds like you need to aggregate first if multiple rows per day are possible:

```
with t2 as (
    select ID, AlertDate, max(Alert) as Alert
    from #t2
    group by ID, AlertDate
), data as (
    select t1.ID, t1.SpecDate,
        row_number() over (partition by t1.ID order by t2.AlertDate) as rn,
        datediff(day, t1.SpecDate, t2.AlertDate) as dn,
        min(t2.AlertDate) over (partition by t1.ID, t1.SpecDate) as firstAlert  
    from #t1 t1 inner join #t2 t2
        on t2.ID = t1.ID
            and t2.Alert = 'Y'
            and t2.AlertDate >= dateadd(day, -2, t1.SpecDate)
), streaks as (
    select ID, SpecDate, count(*) as cnt
    from data
    where firstAlert <= SpecDate
    group by ID, SpecDate, dn - rn
)
select ID, SpecDate, max(cnt) as ConsecutiveAlertDays
from streaks
group by ID, SpecDate;
```

Comment: That is almost there, but it's also returning a count of 1 for ID 'B', SpecDate '2021-05-12'.  This one shouldn't be returned because it's outside the 2 day window with 'B's last 'Y' on '2021-05-08'.  Thank you

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c8d36a/2